# How to detect 2 fingers tap and which views are tap in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm making falling tiles game. I already implemented the normal tile when you tap (single) it will be deleted. Next I want to make the double tile when you tap the 2 tiles at the same time these will be deleted. But I have no idea to detect "whether you tap 2 double tiles at the same time".

The double tiles fall from top of the screen from the bottom of screen. If tiles achieved to the bottom, new tiles will appear from the top of screen.
And now I could detect single tap and tap at the same time by 2 fingers.

How can I make the double tiles?

**UPDATE:**

So far I can detect 2 fingers touches by GestureRecognizer. But can't detect "which views you touched". The log of "gesture.view" is only one view even you touched 2 tiles. What I want to do is like the below code:

```
if gesture.view.count == 2 && gesture.view is GameTileDouble {
    print("touched 2 doubleTiles at the same time")
}
```

Tiles Class

```
class GameTile: UIImageView {

    init(named: String, frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        super.image = (UIImage(named: named))
        super.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Normal Tile Class

```
class GameTileNormal: GameTile {

    let namedDefault: String
    var frameDefault: CGRect
    let isHiddenDefault: Bool
    var isUserInteractionEnabledDefault: Bool
    let colorName: UIColor
    var tileLane: Int

    init(
        named: String,
        frame: CGRect,
        isHidden: Bool = false,
        isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool = true,
        color: UIColor = UIColor.blue,
        lane: Int) {
        namedDefault = named
        isHiddenDefault = isHidden
        frameDefault = frame
        isUserInteractionEnabledDefault = isUserInteractionEnabled
        colorName = color
        tileLane = lane

        super.init(named: named, frame: frame)
        super.isHidden = isHiddenDefault
        super.isUserInteractionEnabled = isUserInteractionEnabledDefault
        super.backgroundColor = colorName

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Double Tile Class

```
class GameTileDouble: GameTile {
    let namedDefault: String
    var frameDefault: CGRect
    let isHiddenDefault: Bool
    let isUserInteractionEnabledDefault: Bool
    let colorName: UIColor
    var tileLane: Int

    init(
        named: String,
        frame: CGRect,
        isHidden: Bool = false,
        isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool = true,
        color: UIColor = UIColor.yellow,
        lane: Int) {
        namedDefault = named
        frameDefault = frame
        isHiddenDefault = isHidden
        isUserInteractionEnabledDefault = isUserInteractionEnabled
        colorName = color
        tileLane = lane

        super.init(named: named, frame: frame)
        super.isHidden = isHiddenDefault
        super.isUserInteractionEnabled = isUserInteractionEnabledDefault
        super.backgroundColor = colorName

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let tileNormal = GameTileNormal.init(named: "normal.png",frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 50, height: 50),isUserInteractionEnabled: true, lane: 1)
        self.view.addSubview(tileNormal)

        let tileDouble1 = GameTileDouble.init(named: "black.png",frame: CGRect(x:150, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50),isUserInteractionEnabled: true, lane: 2)
        self.view.addSubview(tileDouble1)

        let tileDouble2 = GameTileDouble.init(named: "black.png",frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50),isUserInteractionEnabled: true, lane: 3)
        self.view.addSubview(tileDouble2)

        //detect single tap
        let singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(StandardGameViewController.handleSingleTapGesture(_:)))
        singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        singleTapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)

        //detect tap at the same time by 2 fingers
        let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: #selector(StandardGameViewController.handleDoubleTapGesture(_:)))
        doubleTapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

    }

    //something function to move tiles...

    @objc func handleSingleTapGesture(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("single tap")
        //if tapped tileNormal, the normalTile is deleted (removeFromSuperview)
    }

    @objc func handleDoubleTapGesture(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap at the same time by 2 fingers")

        //if tapped doubleTile1 and tileDouble1 and tileDouble2, these tiles will be deleted (this is the point I don't have any idea
    }
```

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal, of course you __can touch__ as many different objects as you want at the same time using various number of fingers independently – that has been the core principal from the very first iPhone-class touch-screens; and it is never too late to familiarise yourself with the [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol?language=objc) class's event-handler mechanism either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to enable multi touch on the `view` on which your tiles are added

```
//Assuming it's on self.view
self.view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
```

*Note: Doing this this will support `N` number of touches.*

---

Then you can make do with only `handleSingleTapGesture:`.
No need for `handleDoubleTapGesture:`.

Just ensure you add a tap gesture on every tile and assign the tap action to `handleSingleTapGesture:` so it will be called for every tile you tap on.

Then simply delete the tile like so:

```
gesture.view?.removeFromSuperview()
```

---

Example:

```
@IBAction func handleSingleTapGesture(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let view = gesture.view else { return }

    print("Current view tapped: ", terminator: "")
    if view.isKind(of: GameTileNormal.self) {
        print("Normal Tile")
    }
    else if view.isKind(of: GameTileDouble.self) {
        print("Double Tile")
    }

    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried it and it did work well! But I can't still detect which tiles you tapped, whether "tileNormal and tileNormal" or "tileNormal and tileDouble" or "tileDouble and tileDouble". The log said "gesture.view is self.view" when I touched 2 fingers at the same time...

Comment: Thank you so much! But I want to know the exact tiles tapped in pairs...

Comment: @bao There's no straightforward or single way to do that. You will need to come up with your own logic or get stuck somewhere so we can help you further.